# How to back up a versioned filesystem (e.g. ext3cow)?

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, versioning

I have been looking at versioned filesystems but I can't find any information on how to back them up.  If my disk dies and I have to restore from a backup, I want to be able to restore the filesystem completely, including the past versions of all files.

Obviously the traditional methods like `cp` and `rsync` won't work, since they'll only copy the current version (right?).  The only other thing I can think of would be to unmount the filesystem and use `dd`, but that's very inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block level backup is your only real hope.

Put your filesystems on top of LVM or a hardware array and then create a snapshot under the filesystem to backup from. Or use dump/dd on the live block device and hope you get something consistent.

FWIW, typical enterprise storage (i.e. NetApp) doesn't normally backup the snapshots of the filesystem - if you're running daily backups, then you already have multiple versions of the file.

What kind of use case are you looking at?

Comment: I have several hundred GB of data that is currently "backed up" via rsync to a couple of mirror machines.  Right now, when somebody modifies a file, they first copy it to another directory and give the file a timestamp extension. What I probably need to do is set up a proper incremental backup.

Comment: Yep, incremental backups sound like they will help. If you're already using rsync, have you looked at using something like dirvish or rsnapshot on the mirror machines - that will give you an incremental/daily/hourly versions of your backups.